# google map show after screen resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I'm having problems with the google map I'm embedding, I don't understand why on load the map not appears and only appear when I resize the window, I went through different solutions in stackoverflow but they don't work for me.

Here is my js code:

```
<script>
function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 31.554606, lng: 74.357158},
          zoom: 14
        });
 google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
               google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            });
         } 
</script>
```

my div

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

when i load application it appears like
[image]

and after re size browser window it appears perfectly like this
[image]

kindly tell me how to fix this problem ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133318/google-maps-api-works-with-browser-inspect-element

Answer (score 9, accepted):

call google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') when your "div id=map" will be visible.
Please see [How do I resize a Google Map with JavaScript after it has loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743214/how-do-i-resize-a-google-map-with-javascript-after-it-has-loaded)

Answer (score 4):

Nothing worked for me. I was using Model box in Bootstrap to load the map. I tried everything for hours. Every time I would load the map I would see a grey box, but as soon as i would resize the browser, it would display the map. Seemed it required resizing of window. So I put all the map functionality into a function called `initmap2()` and displayed the fresh map inside it. and upon clicking i used

```
setTimeout( initMap2, 200 );
```

So as soon as the Modal box would open, it would display the map, and I tried working will `100 milliseconds` but I guess it works with `200+ milliseconds` so I kept `500ms` just to be safe.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I found this working only after combine two things: setTimeout and google resize.

So, at the end of initMap, I set:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function(){
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 
});
```

And create a setTimeout for the initMap like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(initMap, 1000);
});
```

-- 
Edit

To answer @LucaC.: my initMap is a separate js, that I link into the pages. The solution above is defined in this js (the setTimeout only).

But, after a while, I noticed this problem still happening with mobile devices.

Working around: keep the setTimeout for the initMap and on the page I load the map, I've set up

```
$(window).load(function(){
 setTimeout(function(){
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
 }, 250);
});
```

So: i) delay anything that break the map; ii) at the end of all, resize the map after page load :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me. I was using modal box in bootstrap to load the map. i did following code may it will help you

First i load map in **body** with **display:none** like below

```
 <div style="display:none; overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:400px;" id="map"></div>
```

by **initMap** method, map will load properly but we used display=none so that map will not display.
For display that map in model i append the div which have **id="map"** to **id="map-modal"** which is in the model. like below

```
$('#modal-id').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    document.getElementById('map').style.display = "";
    var mapNode = map.getDiv();
    $('#map-modal').append(mapNode);
});
```

May it will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Resize your map without javascript**

step 1: Go to google maps and after searching your location, click on share and
Get the Google Maps Embed
Code

step 2: code will look something like this

```
<iframe src="/" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

step 3: Add a div tag around the embed code. Use the CSS class map-responsive

```
<div class="map-responsive">
<iframe src="/" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

step 4: Add your Google Maps CSS

```
.map-responsive{
overflow:hidden;
padding-bottom:56.25%;
position:relative;
height:0;
}

.map-responsive iframe{
left:0;
top:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
} 


this will make your map responsive to any screen size.!!
```